# Having trouble with SQL command logic - please help

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following statement to fill an Excel spreadsheet with student information, including "actualstudenthours."

The problem is, I want to show all students for which the tblstudentstatus.id = 3, but I also need to show actual student hours for those students. Unfortunately, not all of the students have a corresponding entry in "viewactualstudenthours." This statement completely leaves out those students for which there is no corresponding entry in "viewatualstudenthours."

How do I get all the students to show up where the tblstudentstatus.id = 3?

If there is no entry for them in viewactualstudenthours, it should not omit the student entirely...the student hours fields should just be blank. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$result=mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT tblstudent.first, tblstudent.last,
            LEFT(viewactualstudenthours.ACTUAL_remain,5),
            (SELECT first from tbladdress where tbladdress.id = tblstudent.contact2),
            (SELECT last  from tbladdress where tbladdress.id = tblstudent.contact2),
            tbladdress.address1,tbladdress.city,tbladdress.state,tbladdress.zip1,
            tbladdress.phone, tbladdress.cell, tbladdress.email
            FROM tblstudent, tbladdress, tblstudentstatus, viewactualstudenthours
            WHERE viewactualstudenthours.student_id = tblstudent.id
              AND tblstudent.status = tblstudentstatus.id
              AND tbladdress.id = tblstudent.contact1
              AND tblstudentstatus.id = 3");
```

(*Note*: the editor made the SQL semi-legible - but probably broke every rule in the PHP code book.)

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Edit your question and try it out. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Comment: @junkyjunk: no I'm not. I'm suggesting that your user name of 'junkyjunk' and the fact you registered today, might make people think you are trolling. For your ref: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: less complaints and search for an answer @junkyjunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn to use the explicit join notation introduced in SQL-92 instead of the older comma-separated list of table names in the FROM clause.

You need to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN of the table `tblstudent` with the view `viewactualstudenthours`.  Ignoring the quotes etc needed to make the code work in PHP, you need:

```
SELECT S.first, S.last,
       H.ACTUAL_remain,
       A2.first, A2.last,
       A1.address1, A1.city, A1.state, A1.zip1,
       A1.phone,    A1.cell, A1.email
  FROM tblstudent                  AS S
  JOIN tbladdress                  AS A1 ON S.Contact1 = A1.ID
  JOIN tbladdress                  AS A2 ON S.Contact2 = A2.ID
  JOIN tblstudentstatus            AS T  ON S.Status   = T.ID
  LEFT JOIN viewactualstudenthours AS H  ON S.ID       = H.Student_ID
 WHERE T.id = 3
```

Also learn to use table aliases (the AS clauses) - it simplifies and clarifies the SQL.  And if the schema is up to you, don't prefix the table names with 'tbl' and the view names with 'view' - it is just so much clutter.

Note that I got rid of the sub-selects in the select-list by joining to the Address table twice, with two separate aliases.  I removed the function LEFT(); you can reintroduce it if you need to.

Comment: This seems to work perfectly. I will report back tomorrow as well if there are any problems. I just want to say thank you. If people like you did not exist, I would not know anything. Seeing a concrete practical example transformed like this is so much more helpful and effective to me than reading textbooks and other people's examples. I do think I understand the AS clauses and I am beginning to understand the JOIN and LEFT JOIN as well. Thanks again for your help.